# Simple Firefox extension to blacklist cookies from specific sites / hosts / domains

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

I am looking for a simple Firefox extension to blacklist 1st-party cookies from user-specified sites (well, actually domains or hosts).

*Firefox uses the 'site' terminology a bit incorrectly, but since that's the terminology used by the browser, we won't worry about it for this question.* It's perfectly acceptable if the blacklist must be specified at either the domain or the host level.

The extension ***must*** be able to withstand the user clearing Site Preferences (which can be cleared via Ctrl+Shift+Delete).

Note that Cookie Controller and Cookie Monster are not currently able to meet this requirement.

The cost should be gratis or about what a milkshake costs.  Open-source is preferred but not required.